# What is the difference between superstition, blind faith and omen?

Tags: difference

If someone believes it is bad if it rains on your wedding day or a cat crossing your path is bad then

1. Is it a superstition, an omen or a blind faith ?

   Could someone please elaborate with few another examples ?

Answer (score 2):

All are quite close to each other. But for...

> If a black cat crosses your path, something bad will happen

Considering a 'black cat' bad is *[superstition (read here under the title of 'Bad Luck')](http://www.bbc.co.uk/dna/ptop/plain/A2043)* and if you continue reading further, it says that believing crossing of a black cat will follow bad luck is *belief* (for the believers) or *[misbelief](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misbelief)* (for those who don't believe it).

*Omen* is [a prophetic sign](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/omen) and you forecast something. You foretell the events by some super natural power. Omen could be ***good*** or ***bad***. It's just something that is considered to be a sign of how a future event will take place as mentioned in [Cambridge Dictionary.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/omen) This said, ***as compared*** to blind belief and superstition, it might be positive.

[Blind faith](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Blind%20Faith) is a kind of [dogma](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dogma). You believe something without any evidence/proof.

[Actually, all *faith* are blind! Hebrews defines faith as *“the assurance of things hoped for, the conviction of things **not seen.**”* (Hebrews 11:1, NAS)]

To clarify this, let me come up with three examples -

> I won't believe in the old *superstition* that the number 13 is unlucky. 
>   Whatever you say, Maria will not listen to us. She has 'blind faith' on that sage.
>
> The sign of seeing an owl early in the morning *omens* bad news to come by tonight *(misfortune)* 
>  The sign of seeing angels in my dream last night *omens* good news today *(good fortune)*

[Note that the word 'omen' is used as a verb there].

Comment: The phrase "blind faith" has many connotations.  If your friend offers you a glass of liquid to drink, and you drink it without question, you exercised "blind faith".  Your real faith was in your friend.  You trust he would not give you a glass of acid to drink.  We use that sort of "blind faith" every day.



believe to be true, and doesn't think it can be "proved as true."

"Blind faith" is also used to describe someone's beliefs with which the commenter thinks has been proven false.

Comment: I came up with the example of blind faith that includes everything. Maria would certainly drink anything that the sage gives! :)